# Constructing a Hamiltonian system with a given number of saddles and centers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I construct a hamiltonian system with n saddles and 1 center? It is two dimensional system. I tried various polynomials, but none of it seemed to work. I always end up with at least two centers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you can manage it with polynomials, but you can do it.

The Hamiltonian $H(q,p)$ gives you the system
$$ \eqalign{ \frac{dq}{dt} &=  \dfrac{\partial H}{\partial p}\cr
             \frac{dp}{dt} &= -\dfrac{\partial H}{\partial q}\cr}$$

with equilibria at the critical points of $H$.

Now think of drawing level curves of $H$.  Around the one centre the curves
will be closed.  Each saddle will have level curves crossing in an X shape.  You must be careful to make no closed level curves other that those surrounding that one centre.  For example, you might have a configuration like this in the case $n=5$.

[image]

EDIT: Ah, you can do it with a polynomial: actually a configuration looking very much like that 
occurs with

$$ H(p,q) = p^2 + q^2 + p^5-10p^3q^2+5pq^4 = p^2 + q^2 + \text{Re}((p+iq)^5) $$

or more generally, to have $n \ge 3$ saddles and one centre you could try this with $(p+iq)^n$
instead of $(p+iq)^5$.